# Can one get quality whipped cream by putting only 250 ml (1 cup) whipping cream into a half litre (1 pint) NO2 whipper?

Tags: whipped-cream, whipper

I just bought a 500 ml whipper (Mosa), which is designed to take up to 500 ml whipping cream and a single NO2 cartridge. I'm not sure I want that much whipped cream available to my family at all times; too tempting! Will the whipper work just as effectively with 250 ml (1 cup) of whipping cream or should I consider getting a smaller whipper designed for 250 ml maximum?

Comment: According to my experience (other brand, same principle), it will work fine. But be prepared for a big "szplshhhhh" at the end when the cream is gone but some pressure is left. Sometimes a second gas cartridge can be neccessary if too little pressure is generated by a single one due to more empty space.

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious if that's other people's experience too.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by "quality".  I've used my 500ml, half full, plenty of times.  If you like a stiffer cream, you might need to give it two charges.  Make sure you turn over the whipper and shake the cream to the dispensing end before dispensing.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it lots of times and never needed a second cartridge. It helps to shake the unit while the gas is going in, to distribute it better, and to use very fine sugar.